# How to add default value for varchar value in xampp

Tags: mysql

[image]i am trying to add a default value in Xampp.
i set it as in the picture, but when i add 1 more product, if i left i in blank, it will be blank, i mean it will not have a value as default.
Do you have any idea.
my code is:

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    //lấy thông tin từ các form bằng phương thức POST
    $tennsx = $_POST["tennsx"];
    $diachi = $_POST["diachi"];
    $sdt = $_POST["sdt"];
    $mieuta = $_POST["mieuta"];
    if ($tennsx == "" || $diachi == "" || $sdt == "" ) {
        echo '<h4 align=center style="color: red;">Vui lòng nhập đầy đủ thông tin</h4>';
    }else{
        //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nhasx(
            tennsx,
            diachi,
            sdt,
            mieuta
            ) VALUES (
            '$tennsx',
            '$diachi',
            '$sdt',
            '$mieuta'
        )";
        // thực thi câu $sql với biến conn lấy từ file connection.php
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        header('Location:manu_management.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `||` to `&&`  in `if ($tennsx == "" || $diachi == "" || $sdt == "" )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Mysql assume you want to insert the empty values instead of default values. You need to omit the field with default values if no value at all to insert, see following code :

```
 // simply check if variable $mieuta is empty
 // goes here
 if ( $mieuta === "" ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO nhasx(
        tennsx,
        diachi,
        sdt                  
        ) VALUES (
        '$tennsx',
        '$diachi',
        '$sdt'
    )";
 }
 else {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO nhasx(
        tennsx,
        diachi,
        sdt,
        mieuta
        ) VALUES (
        '$tennsx',
        '$diachi',
        '$sdt',
        '$mieuta'
    )";
 }
```

Default values should work if you omit the field name and value from query string. This kind of method come in handy when we want to insert default `date created column`.

For better approach use this :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO nhasx(
    tennsx,
    diachi,
    sdt,
    mieuta                 
    ) VALUES (
    '$tennsx',
    '$diachi',
    '$sdt',
    '".($mieuta ==='') ? 'MY DEFAULT VALUE' : $mieuta."'
)";
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me but you should change `if ( $mieuta !== "" )` into `if ( $mieuta == "" )`!

Comment: But the second code can not run, i have to use the first code, anw thank you.

Comment: Yeah, i did't test it, it should work. just need to tweak around single and double quote. Welcome mate.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `xxxx` (
  `username` varchar(15) NOT NULL default 'abc'
)
```

try MySQL like this.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'abc',
  `test` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
INSERT INTO `dbName`.`test` (`id` ,`test`)VALUES (NULL , '1');
```

Comment: i did set it as default like you say, but it's not work

Comment: When you run mysql ,don't include the blank name and value. If the value is blank.

Answer (score 0):

In  your code you have set mieuta = $mieuta while inserting a new record so as per priority it would insert value from $mieuta. please remove and try again as of like below code.

```
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    //lấy thông tin từ các form bằng phương thức POST
    $tennsx = $_POST["tennsx"];
    $diachi = $_POST["diachi"];
    $sdt = $_POST["sdt"];
    $mieuta = $_POST["mieuta"];
    if ($tennsx == "" || $diachi == "" || $sdt == "" ) {
        echo '<h4 align=center style="color: red;">Vui lòng nhập đầy đủ thông tin</h4>';
    }else{
        //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
        $sql = "INSERT INTO nhasx(
            tennsx,
            diachi,
            sdt
            ) VALUES (
            '$tennsx',
            '$diachi',
            '$sdt'
        )";
        // thực thi câu $sql với biến conn lấy từ file connection.php
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        header('Location:manu_management.php');
    }
}
```